# What's the best way to serialize a scala case class that has elements that aren't serializable?

Tags: scala

If you have a Scala case class that looks like:

```
case class Fnord(x: Parcelable, y: Parcelable)
```

Where Parcelable doesn't extend Serializable, but does have a way to return a ByteArray of itself (something that does implement Serializable).

How to do you make the case class Serializable?  Is there a way to do custom (de)serialization on particular fields?

(I'm solving it right now by creating a simple wrapper class that is serializable and using that in the case classes, but it'd be nice to skip that step.)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [java.io.Externalizable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/Externalizable.html).  It allows a class to manually serialize and restore its fields.